# Python program function

Tags: python, function

I understand completely that I have to do this assignment on my own. BUT, I'm a bit confused about the language of this second question.

```
def getRVal(pressure_change,viscosity,length,radius, density , choice) 
( this is what I've got so far)
```

A  function called `getRVal` that:

– Has six input parameters: pressure change, viscosity, length, radius, density and a final
parameter called **choice ( ?**; and
– returns a calculated value as determined by the value of the parameter choice.

If choice equals 1, return the maximum possible pressure drop for flow to be laminar.

If choice equals 2, return the minimum fluid viscosity required for flow to be laminar.

If choice equals 3, return the minimum tube length required for flow to be laminar.

If choice equals 4, return the maximum possible tube radius for flow to be laminar.

Note that when calculating each of these minimum/maximum values, the corresponding
input parameter will not be used in the function, so it does not matter what value is passed
in.

For example, when calculating minimum viscosity, the value of the viscosity parameter
is not used; when calculating maximum radius, the value of the radius parameter is not
used, and so on

Comment: You could start by reading the [Python tutorial on defining functions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Answer (score 1):

your questions is asking you to make a function getFlow which accepts four arguments(pressure change, viscosity, length, and radius), the function getFlow is expected to make use of these arguments and calculate Hagen-Poiseuille flow rate in mL/sec and return this value.
something like

```
def getFlow(pressure_change, viscosity, length, radius):
    hagen_flow_rate= (formula to calculate flow rate)
    return hagen_flow_rate

#take input of the values

pressure_change = float(raw_input("Enter Pressure Change"))
viscosity = float(raw_input("Enter viscosity"))
length = float(raw_input("Enter length"))
radius = float(raw_input("Enter radius"))

#call the function here passing the values

getFlow(pressure_change, viscosity, length, radius)
```

Comment: I got an typing error from this idle program ( something about a float? when I actually type down the hagen p equation): def getFlow(pressure_change, viscosity, length, radius):
    flowrate= (pressure_change*pi*radius*radius*radius*radius)/(8*viscosity*length)
    return (flowrate)

Comment: i have edited the code, try it out now, if you still get error, please mention the exact error you get.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function that takes several parameters easily, e.g:

```
def getFlow(p_c, visc, length, radius):
    #these 4 variables are now available in the function name space, use them
    flowrate = p_c*visc*length*radius #insert real formula here ;)
    return flowrate
```